# botones dinamicos - obtener el Id del boton presionado desde javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un vista, que de manera dinámica, crea varios elementos del tipo `Button` de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach (PacienteSeleccionDispensarDto paciente in @Model)
{
<input type="button" name="btnPaciente"             id="btn_@paciente.IdPaciente" 
value="@paciente.NombrePaciente" onclick="fnProcesaPaciente()" />
}
```

en el evento `onclick`, puse la función `fnProcesaPaciente`, en la cual necesito rescatar el id del boton que presiono el usuario, y estaba intentando de la siguiente manera

```
 var PacienteId = $(this.data("id"));
```

pero al parecer esto no sirve, porque los botones se crean en una vista parcial, no en la vista principal (no se si esto tendrá alguna incidencia).

como puedo saber el Id del boton presionado?

Saludos

Comment: Disculpa, pero no tendrías que agregar **#** a el `id`

Comment: onclick="fnProcesaPaciente(@paciente.id) es una opcion

Comment: estimados, gracias por la ayuda. no se si faltaba el #, probablemente si, pero lo qu eme indica Jose Maria, funciona perfecto, ya que tengo en la funcion el id a traves del parametro. muchas gracias

Answer (score 8):

Si añade una función al evento `onClick` del Botón envíele por parámetro dicho botón así será más fácil capturar el valor desde la función haciendo uso de la palabra reservada `this`

```
<input type="button" name="btnPaciente"         id="btn_@paciente.IdPaciente" 
value="@paciente.NombrePaciente" onclick="fnProcesaPaciente(this)" />
```

Para luego desde su función capturar el valor , accediendo al atributo `id` de `comp` que sería el `botón` que se dio `click`

```
function fnProcesaPaciente(comp){
  let id = comp.id;
  console.log(id);
}
```

**JQUERY**

Haciendo uso del método [on(evento,componente,function)](http://api.jquery.com/on/) para que escuché el evento `click` que se realice en todos los controles `Input` de `type=button`, si se da el evento accedemos al id del elemento mediante la palabra reservada `this` que hace referencia al control que se dio `click` y a la propiedad `id`.

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(event) {
    let id = this.id;
 console.log("Se presionó el Boton con Id :"+ id)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="e" value="e" id="idn1">
<input type="button" name="e" value="e" id="idn2">
<input type="button" name="e" value="e" id="idn3">
<input type="button" name="e" value="e" id="idn4">
```

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a probar esta solucion. saludos